# Expression of an integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, symbolic

I am doing the following integral in *Mathematica* with $a>0$:

$$\iint e^{-\frac{(x_{1}+x_{2}-2b)^2}{4a}}dx_{1}dx_{2}$$

My code is

```
Integrate[
 Exp[-2 ((x + y)/2 - b)^2/(2*a)], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]
(* ∞ Sqrt[Sign[a]] *)
```

Although the integration is infinity, I wish to obtain an approximate close form of the integral as a function of `a`, `b`. Is this possible using *Mathematica* ? How to do this?

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Just to be clear, you wish to approximate infinity as a function of two variables?

Answer (score 7):

What about computing a general $t$-bound integral:

```
expr = Integrate[Exp[-2 ((x + y)/2 - b)^2/(2*a)], {x, -t, t}, {y, -t, t}];
```

And then expanding in series around $t=\infty$:

```
Series[expr, {t, Infinity, 3}] // Normal // PowerExpand // FullSimplify
```

$\frac{a^2 \left(e^{-\frac{(b-t)^2}{a}}+e^{-\frac{(b+t)^2}{a}}\right)}{t^2}-4 a e^{-\frac{b^2}{a}}-4 \sqrt{\pi } \sqrt{a} b
   \text{erf}\left(\frac{b}{\sqrt{a}}\right)+4 \sqrt{\pi } \sqrt{a} t$

You can see that at this limit expression tends to infinity linearly in $t$ as

$4 \sqrt{\pi } \sqrt{a} t$

because other terms become smaller as $t$ goes to infinity. You better check this logic, I did not dwell on this. Independence of $b$ makes sense.

Comment: thx, this is valuable to restrict within finite bounds t.

Answer (score 4):

If you change the variables: `y1=x1+x2; y2=x2` you get to another expression:

[image]

where all the integration limits are +/- infinities. The first integral is just equal to infinity, while the second is

```
    Integrate[Exp[-(y1 - 2 b)^2/(4 a)], {y1, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, 
 Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0}]

(* 2 Sqrt[a] Sqrt[\[Pi]]  *)
```

I hope this helps. Have fun!

Comment: thx You were right after change of variables, we could have a expression.